# Testing a SQL Query for True or False

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT # FROM users WHERE onduty = 1 AND loc_id = '{$site}';"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I simply want to test if this is true or false.  If it returns 0 rows, I want next line to be something like:

```
if (!$result) { //do this; }
```

However, in my test, I am getting false when I know it should be true.  Is this sound logic here?

(note, yes I know I should be using `mysqli_query`, that is not what I am asking here)******

**ANSWER:
This is what I used:**

```
$login_state = false;
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE onduty = 1 AND loc_id = '{$site}';"))) {
    $login_state = true;
}
```

Comment: why `{$site}';";` ?? looks like should be `{$site}'"; `

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: @NullPointer, I don't care for URL shorteners and some of the wording that snippet uses, otherwise I would.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`EXISTS`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE onduty = 1 AND loc_id = '{$site}') AS test;
```

Your original query would return "no row" if no row is found that matches the criteria. This one returns `TRUE` (`1`) or `FALSE` (`0`) every time.

In cases where there can be multiple rows matching the criteria and you are only interested whether at least one rows exists, performance of `EXISTS` is superior to a plain query. It can stop as soon as the first row is found and only returns `0` or `1`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=496e4c24551f07a2c82b63aeef6ad3cb)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c514cd/1)</sub>

Comment: if I replaced my SQL query with the one you have, do I still do `  $result = mysql_query($sql);` and $result would be either true or false?

Comment: @KickingLettuce: Yes, or rather `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`, as MySQL puts it.

Comment: I am actually getting `Resource id #16` instead of true or false.

Comment: You will still receive a mysql resource from the query. You need to fetch the first result from the resource. But you are guaranteed that there will always be a result, and never an empty result set. Use `mysql_result` to fetch the result from the resource.

Comment: sorry for the delay.  I used your answer.  Just had to figure out the PHP logic around it.  Will update question above.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: What you added in the question does not use `EXISTS`. The difference is in performance as I explained in my question.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. I must have switched gears at the last minute.  I believe you on performance, but for these needs, it is a very, very light weight web app and this way works for me.  Thanks for your input, I'll still leave your comment correct cause, in theory, I do think its the better option and I may convert to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check number of rows returned on executing query.

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows==0)
{
//nothing returned
}
else
{

//rows returned
}
```

For corresponding mysqli implementation ,see [mysqli_stmt_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)