# why only if statement works? Any mistakes in my code(count() statement)?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, count, return, return-value

I've a problem with mysql source. 
I have no idea how to fix it. 
It works at mysql but something weird.

For example: 
 If i have no rows in ID/PWD column, if statement is work and  return 1. i really don't know why... but 'if statement' is working. i think it should go to 'else if statement' and return 2; or should go to 'else statement' and return 0..! plz help me

```js
var mysqlUtil = module.exports = {
 Login: function(nickname, password) {
      if(connect.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + TABLE + ' WHERE ID = ? AND PWD = ?', [nickname, password]))
      { 
       return 1;
      }
      else if(connect.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + TABLE + ' WHERE auth_ID = ? AND auth_PWD = ?', [nickname, password]))
      {
       return 2;
      }
      else
      {
       return 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: @AkramFares it's javascript!

Answer (score 0):

안녕
,

You might prefer something like PostGres or mongoDb if your working with javascript backend.....

Guide on MySQl/javascript:
http://www.codediesel.com/nodejs/querying-mysql-with-node-js/

if statements need a true or false condition.

Try using EXISTS to get a boolean value from a mySQL query:

[Testing a SQL Query for True or False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784670/testing-a-sql-query-for-true-or-false)

or....

```
        Login: function(nickname, password) {

        connect.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + TABLE + ' WHERE ID = ? AND PWD = ?', [nickname, password], function (err, results){
     if (err || !results.ID == nickname){  
 console.log("씨발");}
    else {
        console.log("만세");
return results
        };
    });
```

if results.ID does not equal nickname or error occurs, then fail condition.